# Recursive search on predefined file name in different folders

Tags: linux, grep

So I have this file structure:

```
/var/www/html/website1/app/config/database.php
/var/www/html/website2/app/config/database.php
...
```

what I need is finding a certain string in every `database.php` files, I've tried

```
grep -nrw "string" /var/www/html/*/app/config/*
```

but it doesn't seem to recognize the path.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to achieve what I'm after.

Comment: If you are specifying all your database.php files using a wildcard, you do not need to search recursively through directories (`-r`). If all your web sites follow that path structure, `grep "string" /var/www/html/*/app/config/database.php` should be sufficient. If that path expansion results in zero files, then correct it to point at where the files *really* are.

Answer (score 0):

`find /var -maxdepth 5 -mindepth 5 -name database.php -type f | xargs grep -nrw "string"`

If you expect "[newlines or or types of white space](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)" in the filenames:

```
find /var -maxdepth 5 -mindepth 5 -name database.php -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -nrw "string"
```

Comment: What happens if directory names have spaces in them? And how did you determine optimal depth values? Can you explain your answer better?

Comment: To handle white space in filenames use options `-print0` and `-0` for `find` and `xargs` commands respectively (added to my answer). The file we are looking for is five directory levels below the directory given as an argument to find (`/var`).

Answer (score 0):

If all the files you'll be searching through will follow the pattern of the ones in your question, then you don't need a recursive search, you can do this with globbing alone. Your `*` can exist (and be expanded) anywhere in the path, not just at the end.

```
grep -n -F -w "string" /var/www/html/*/app/config/database.php
```

This has the advantage of ONLY looking for the paths that you've specified as important.

Note that since you've said you're searching for a string rather than a RE, the `-F` option may be appropriate.

If this doesn't find files which you believe should exist, you might try something like this:

```
find /var/www/html/*/app -name database.php -print
```

to verify that you're actually looking in the right place for this file.